# Scraping does not export to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying my first time to scrape the information from website and export it to excel file. However, not the whole information is scraped, nor the file is created for the export.

This is what I get in anaconda:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>firstwebscrape.py
brand:  []
product_name: ASRock Radeon RX 5700 XT DirectX 12 RX 5700 XT TAICHI X 8G OC+ Video Card
product_price: €446,99
```

Here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/lt-en/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card'

#opening up the connection grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs all containers
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename= "123.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("a",{"class":"title"})

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    product_price = price_container[0].text.strip()

print("brand: ", brand)
print("product_name: " + product_name)
print("product_price: " + product_price)

f.write(str(brand) + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Please explain more in retail what the expected result should be: "However, not the whole information is scraped,..." is unclear.

Comment: I need that all information from that site containers will be scraped. As I understand the only last value is saved and scraped. So I should make a loop to scrape all containers and export information to excel as .csv file.

Comment: You just need to change your loop and your code runs fine – see my answer.

Comment: If your matter is solved please mark the answer as accepted so that others can see that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs fine. Just correct this in your loop:

```
for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("a",{"class":"title"})

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    product_price = price_container[0].text.strip()

    # these code lines have to be in your for loop!
    print("brand: ", brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("product_price: " + product_price)

    f.write(str(brand) + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")
```

You want to print and save for every item in your iteration over `containers`. Otherwise only the last item gets saved to your CSV.

Comment: Thank you. In anaconda I get all the values now!
The excel file is created, however I cannot open it. It is saving in System32 folder. Once I press it, I get an error that the file cannot be located. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
I do not understand whats wrong since I see file, I can double click on it, but I get an error that there is no file there. Strange. Digging more into this.

Comment: You're welcome. And regarding the Excel file: Have you tried to set an absolute path for `filename` the points to say your Windows desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that splits the job between getting the data, extracting and writing the result.  It also leaves the job of writing the csv data to the `csv`module.

```
import csv
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extract_brand(c):
    """Locate brand

    At most 3 words in brand
    """
    tag = c.find('img', class_='lazy-img')
    tmp = tag.get('alt')
    m = re.match(r'(\w+\s?){1,3}', tmp)
    brand = m.group(0).rstrip() if m else 'No Brand Found'
    return brand


def extract_product(c):
    title_container = c.find('a', class_='item-title')
    product_name = title_container.string
    return product_name.replace(',', '|').strip()


def extract_price(c):
    price_container = c.find('li', class_='price-current')
    tmp = price_container.string
    if not tmp:
        tmp = ''.join(price_container.stripped_strings)
    m = re.match(r'(.\d[\d.,]+)', tmp.strip())
    product_price = m.group(0) if m else "?"
    return product_price


def extract_from(page):
    """Extract data for each product

    Return a list containing data for one product per list item.
    """
    containers = page.find_all('div', class_='item-container')
    data = []
    for container in containers:
        item = []
        item.append(extract_brand(container))
        item.append(extract_product(container))
        item.append(extract_price(container))
        data.append(item)
    return data


def write2csv(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fd = csv.writer(csvfile)
        headers = ["brand", "product_name", "product_price"]
        fd.writerow(headers)
        fd.writerows(data)


def get_html_from(url, parser='html.parser'):
    with uReq(url) as uClient:
        page_html = uClient.read()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, parser)
    return page_soup


my_url = ('https://www.newegg.com/global/lt-en/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/'
          'Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card')

page = get_html_from(my_url)
data = extract_from(page)

filename = "1234.csv"
write2csv(filename, data)
```